# Java: Turning a Matrix into a List: my add method is not working and I don't know why

Tags: java, sorting, matrix

I keep on get an error that says my add method says no suitable method found. The goal of the program is to get all the values of a matrix into a list and I can not get it to work because it keeps on giving me an error at this line:

```
list.add(mat[i][j]);
```

The entire code looks like this:

```
List<Integer> go(int[][] mat) 
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) 
        {
            list.add(mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You're using an `ArrayList<String>` instead of an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: Try ` List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Integer> go(int[][] mat) 
{
    int capacity = mat.length * mat[0].length; // Not needed.
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(capacity);
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) 
        {
            list.add(mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

String instead of Integer. And better style is to let the variable already be a List.

Immediately reserving the right amount of list entries is an optimization: no resizing during adding of values, and not reserving too many room.

In fact a linear array might also be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns a `List<Integer>`, but your `list` object is declared as an `ArrayList<String>`, which you are trying to add `mat[i][j]` to.  Furthermore, `mat[i][j]` is itself an `int`, so `list` should be an `ArrayList<Integer>`.